# Adding information

Tags: python, json

So I want to make a file that adds a certain id. So if I run the code it will add information instead of wiping previous information. The following is my current code.

```
import json

with open("pcodes.json") as codes:
        data = json.load(codes)
        data['pcodes'].append({
            "code1111":12345
        })
```

Comment: Can you please add more information about what the difficulty is that you have encountered? This code *does* add a value and does not wipe anything, just like you wanted.

Comment: Code looks fine, but you're not modifying the file because you've opened it as read-only